# OOP - Mysqi Connection: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DBConnection::prepare()

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm a newbie at PHP OOP and I have a problem with my code and i keep getting an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DBConnection::prepare() in E:\xampp\htdocs\includes\user_functions.php:35 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\includes\process_login.php(12): User::login('admin', 'aa17a9b71574929...', Object(DBConnection)) #1 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\includes\user_functions.php on line 35

The error is in the prepare statement and i can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong. I can't seem to get my head around. I Assume it has something to do with the construct object

I have already created a class for my connection, which i call upon in my login script. Once i am in the script, i call the login function. It seems to accept the connection, but the issue arises, when i call the prepare() function.

Here is my login script:

```php
<?php
  include_once ('db_connect.php'); //Here i define my connection
  include_once ('user_functions.php'); //In this file my functions

  $mysqli = new DBConnection(); //i create a new object of the connection

  User::sec_session_start(); // This is the script in my user_functions.php
  if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $password = $_POST['p']; 

      if (User::login($email, $password, $mysqli) == true) {
          header('Location: ../index.php');
      } else {
          header('Location: ../error.php?error=1');
      }
  } else {
      echo 'Invalid Request';
  }

?>
```

Here is my db_connect.php

```php
<?php
  include_once ('psl-config.php');   // Da functions.php nicht included ist

  class DBConnection {

    protected $mysqli;
    protected  $db_host = HOST;
    protected  $db_username = USER;
    protected  $db_password = PASSWORD;
    protected  $db_name = DATABASE;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->mysqli= new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_name)
        or die($this->mysqli->error);

         return $this->mysqli;
    }

    //$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE); //This method worked previously, when not done with OOP
    public function real_escape_string($str) {
      return $this->mysqli->real_escape_string();
    }

     function __destruct() {
       $this->mysqli->close();
     }
  }
?>
```

Here is my user_functions.php

```php
<?php
require_once ('db_connect.php');
  class User {

    public function __construct($mysqli) {
      return $this->mysqli=$mysqli;
    }

    function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
      if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_id, username, password, salt //This is where the error occurs
          FROM users
          WHERE email = ? OR username = ?
          LIMIT 1")) {
          $stmt->bind_param('ss', $email, $email);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->store_result();
          $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password);
          $stmt->fetch();

          if ($db_password == $password) {
            $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            $user_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $user_id);
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/",
                                                        "",
                                                        $username);
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['login_string'] = hash('sha512',
                      $password . $user_browser);
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've got `DBConnection` instance in your `$mysqli` variable, not `$this->mysqli` from `__construct()` call. Try to make separate method in your `DBConnection` class, that returns `$this->mysqli`. Something like this:

```
...
  public function __construct() {
      $this->mysqli= new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_name)
      or die($this->mysqli->error);
  }

  public function getConnection()
  {
    return $this->mysqli;
  }
...
```

And make `$mysqli` like this:

```
$mysqli = (new DBConnection())->getConnection();
```

Comment: $mysqli = (new DBConnection())->getConnection(); Seems plausible, but how can i pass this onto my User class? I keep on getting the same error?

I did this:
$mysqli = (new DBConnection())->getConnection();
in my db_connect.php and when i access the login function in my User class (in user_functions.php) i get the error. Should i create the getConnection in my User class also?

Comment: First, you need to create an instance of `User` object and pass there your $mysqli: `$user = new User($mysqli);`. Then, in your `login(...` call use `$this->mysqli` instead of `$mysqli`. Don't call `login()` like this `User::login(...`. Call `$user->login(..`. But most of all, you should search for some PHP OOP tutorials in web. Questions you've asked are quite simple if you know the basis. Try something like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_object_oriented.htm).

Answer (score 1):

`return $this->mysqli;` this does not work. Have a look at this: https://3v4l.org/OZjEl

You could add a method `getConnection` or try to extend the MySQLi class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  <?php
      class DBConnection{
            private $db;

            public function __construct(){
               try {
                 $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
                 echo "Connection Successful";

               }catch(PDOException $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
               }    
            }

           public function getConnection() {
                 if ($this->db instanceof PDO) {
                    return $this->db;
                 }
           }
      }
?>
```

And then create instance of class and get conn object

```
$db_instance = new DBConnection();
$conn = $db_instance->getConnection();
```